# Azure website resource template error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I'm attempting to use the [AzureResourceManager](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/) PowerShell module to create and configure a website.  I started with a template file generated by Visual Studio, which works fine when I use it via `New-AzureResourceGroup -TemplateFile website.json`.

So now I'm trying to tweak the template file to configure the site.  I'm trying to set the php and .NET Framework versions.  According to the [schema](http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01/Microsoft.Web.json) these properties are set via a config object in a resources array.

Here's the website section of my json template.  The "resources" section is what I added:

```
    {
        "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
        "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "location": "[parameters('siteLocation')]",
        "tags": {
            "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]": "Resource"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('siteName')]",
            "serverFarm": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]"
        },
        "resources": [
            {
                "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
                "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
                "name": "config",
                "properties": {
                    "name": "config",
                    "phpVersion": "",
                    "netFrameworkVersion": "V4.5"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

When I pass this template to `Test-AzureResourceGroupTemplate` I get this error:

```
Code    : InvalidTemplate
Message : Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'config' for type 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config' has 
          incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root 
          resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name'.
```

I can't find any documentation on this.  Does anyone know what this error means, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Basic troubleshooting of the ARM template deployment is given here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors/

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Never fails, as soon as I write out the question I figure out the answer.

The error means that because this is a nested resource (the config object is nested inside the site object) the name needs to reflect this.  So instead of `config` the name should be something like `mysite/config`.  I also needed to add the `dependsOn` section.  Here's the template that validated successfully:

```
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('siteName'), '/config')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('siteName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "phpVersion": "",
            "netFrameworkVersion": "V4.5"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: just in case anyone is having the same error while trying to add 'nested' appsettings of connectionstrings, 1 head the above '/' advice, or add some more website resources like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396154/set-arm-template-web-appsetting/40400595#40400595

Comment: For anyone else needing it, here is the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/child-resource-name-type

Answer (score 22):

I hit the same issue and neither of the other answers worked for me, turns out there's actually slightly more to this than the other answers show. Firstly, for a root level resource, [the docs specify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-invalid-template-errors#incorrect-segment-lengths) it must:

> ...have one less segment in the name than in the resource type

In other words if you're creating a:

```
"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites"
```

Then as the name must have one less segment than the type, we can only use a single segment for the name in this example, i.e. one:

```
"name": "MySite"
```

For a nested resource the rule is:

> the type and name have the same number of segments

However this assumes that you are shortening a nested resource's type e.g. creating a type of "Microsoft.Web/sites/config" as a nested resource within a parent of type "Microsoft.Web/sites" and for the nested resource specifying:

```
"type": "config"
```

So here you can also only specify a single segment name, e.g.:

```
"name": "MyConfig"
```

So putting that all together you have:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "name": "MySite",
  "various other properties": ...,
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "config",
      "name": "MyConfig"
      "various other properties": ...
    }
  ]
}
```

If on the other hand you specify the full type name in the nested resource (as shown in the accepted answer) you need to resort to the root naming convention of having one less segment in the name than the type! Converting the above you'd have:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "name": "MySite",
  "various other properties": ...,
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
      "name": "MySite/MyConfig"
      "various other properties": ...
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The 'incorrect segment lengths' error message is difficult to understand for non-English native so there's explanation in plain English/json:
For example, you have a resource of type  `Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles` resource and for some reason you need to define nested resource having type  `Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/ExternalEndpoints` as a separate resource.

The nested resource must have name `parent_resource_name/nested_res_name`

The correct (simplified) schema is:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles",
  "name": "[variables('trafManagerProfileName')]",
   ...
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/ExternalEndpoints",
  "name": "[concat(variables('trafManagerProfileName'), '/Endpoint', copyIndex())]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Network/trafficManagerProfiles/', variables('trafManagerProfileName'))]",
    "[parameters('app_name')]" # where the endpoint should look at
  ],
   ...
}
```

p.s. you might be interested in this question as well if you need to generate nested resources dynamically based on count of third resource: [How do I dynamically generate Traffic Manager endpoints in an ARM template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609925/how-do-i-dynamically-generate-traffic-manager-endpoints-in-an-arm-template/49772491#49772491)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this happened to me with Vnet-peering. I used this template from Microsoft's documentation:

```json
{
     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
     "parameters": {
     },
     "variables": {
     },
 "resources": [
         {
         "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
         "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings",
         "name": "myVnetA/myVnetAToMyVnetB",
         "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
         "properties": {
         "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
         "allowForwardedTraffic": false,
         "allowGatewayTransit": false,
         "useRemoteGateways": false,
             "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
             "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription ID>/resourceGroups/PeeringTest/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myVnetB"
             }
         }
         }
     ]
}
```

But then I modified the `name` to be, for example, `vneta-tovnetb` and it gave the me error.

If I use the `vneta/vnetb` as the `name` it does validate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. I've updated your answer to provide improved formatting; please review the Markdown so you can use similar formatting in future posts. Can you verify that the solution here is to use `vneta/vnetb` for the `name`?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Thanks for modifying my answer. yes setting the name to be vneta/vnetb will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer here.
For child resources, the type and name have the same number of segments. This number of segments makes sense because the full name and type for the child includes the parent name and type. Therefore, the full name still has one less segment than the full type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-invalid-template

Comment: I like how the documentation claims that "this makes sense" even though it is completely arbitrary and unintuitive

Comment: @codemonkeh Just microsoft things *(light piano sounds)*